# How to call asynchronous recursive functions after each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, promise

I am using trying to have typing text in a div that has three different lines of text. So I want to call the function typed_text() for line one, then call it again for line two, then line three. I tried to use promises, but I was lost when it came to using setTimeout() and recursion.

I call the function something like this.

```
typed_text("#line_one", frame.text_one, 0, 25)
        typed_text("#line_two", frame.text_two, 0, 25)
        typed_text("#line_three", frame.text_three, 0, 25)

        function typed_text(div, text, index, interval)
        {
            if (quit_typed_text == true) {
                interval = 0;
            }
            if (index < text.length) {
                $(div).append(text[index++]);
                setTimeout(function() {typed_text(div, text, index, interval); }, interval);
            } else {
                click_disabled = false;
            }

        }
```

Edit: Here is what I was attempting using recursion and promises

```
    typed_text("#text_one", frame.text_one, 0, 25).then(typed_text("#text_two", frame.text_two, 0, 25));

function typed_text(div, text, index, interval)
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        if (quit_typed_text == true) {
            interval = 0;
        }
        if (index >= text.length) {
            click_disabled = false;
            resolve();
        }
    }).then(function() {
        if (index < text.length) {
            $(div).append(text[index++]);
            /* Problem is here, setTimeout.then() does not exist as a function */
            setTimeout(function() {typed_text(div, text, index, interval); }, interval);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `I tried to use promises` - doesn't look like it

Comment: I didn't post my code using promises as I had no idea where I was going with recursion. If not for recursion I think the solution would have worked. I can share what I had if that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using promises, your typed_text function can be rewritten as follows

```
function typed_text(div, text, index, interval) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var doit = function() {
            if (quit_typed_text == true) {
                interval = 0;
            }
            if (index < text.length) {
                $(div).append(text[index++]);
                setTimeout(doit, interval);
            } else {
                click_disabled = false; // not sure this should be here
                resolve();
            }
        };
        doit(); // oops forgot this line
    });
}
```

Then, to use it, simply use promise chaining as follows:

```
typed_text("#line_one", frame.text_one, 0, 25).then(function() {
    return typed_text("#line_two", frame.text_two, 0, 25);
}).then(function() {
    return typed_text("#line_three", frame.text_three, 0, 25);
}).then(function() {
    // all done here - perhaps this is where click_disabled = false should be?
});
```

Comment: Looks very promising, thanks! Though I'm am having trouble with 'doit'. It doesn't seem to call that function,  i.e I put console.log('entered') as the first line in the function and it seems to never be called.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no asynchronous function in your code, so why don't you call your function "typed_text" in a setTimeOut ?

By example :

```
setTimeout(function() { typed_text("#line_one", frame.text_one, 0); }, 25);
setTimeout(function() { typed_text("#line_two", frame.text_two, 0); }, 50);
setTimeout(function() { typed_text("#line_three", frame.text_three, 0); }, 75);


function typed_text(div, text, index){
    if (quit_typed_text == true) interval = 0;
    if (index < text.length) $(div).append(text[index++]);
    else click_disabled = false;
}
```

Could this be ok for you ?

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately with your solution I lose the recursive call to output text in a typing manner to the div. I'd like the user to see the first time typed character by character, then the second line will type character by character, all using the same time out interval of 25. I am currently trying something similar though to see if I can make it work.